# Closed immersions of affine schemes: $\operatorname{res}_{Y,U_i}(f^\ast s)$ is "given by an element" of $S_i$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This theorem is from the Red Book of Varieties and Schemes, page 147.  I'm stuck on a detail in the second paragraph of the proof.

[image]

Let $U_i = \operatorname{Spec} S_i$.  For $s \in B \subseteq \mathcal O_X(X) = R$, we have the element $f^{\ast}(X)(s) = f^{\ast}(s)$ in $\mathcal O_Y(Y)$, where $f^{\ast}: \mathcal O_X \rightarrow f_{\ast} \mathcal O_Y$ is the surjective morphism of ringed spaces defining the closed immersion.

I believe that the notation $\operatorname{res}_{Y,U_i}(f^\ast s)$ denotes the restriction of $f^\ast s$ to the open set $Y \cap U_i$ of $Y$, that is $f^\ast s|_{Y \cap U_i}$.

But $f^\ast s$ seems like it is the image under some homomorphism of an element $\sigma_i$ of $\mathcal O_{X\mid U}(U) = \mathcal O_X(U)$.  The element $\sigma$ should be $s\mid U$, but what is the homomorphism?

I believe it should be possible to define some morphism of schemes $j: Y \cap U_i \rightarrow U_i$, even a closed immersion, such that the diagram

$$\begin{matrix} U_i & \rightarrow & X \\ \uparrow j & & \uparrow f \\ Y \cap U_i & \rightarrow & Y \end{matrix}$$

commutes, which I think would give me the required homomorphism.  Is this what is really going on, or am I misunderstanding the argument in the proof?  If I am correct, why is this morphism $j$ not mentioned explicitly?

**Edit:** I think I see it.  Perhaps the affine schemes $\operatorname{Spec} S_i$ were not intended to be open subschemes of $X$, but rather open in $Y$.  That would make a lot more sense, and the above argument can be avoided.

Comment: If you write \operatorname{Spec} S_i, you see $\operatorname{Spec} S_i,$ with no need to manually add a space after $\operatorname{Spec}$, nor to adjust the spacing when you write $\operatorname{Spec}(S_i),$ where the software adds less space after $\operatorname{Spec}$ than it does in the version without parentheses. Context-depending spacing without manual adjustment on both the left and the right results from proper use of \operatorname{}. I edited accordingly.